# Report using data _Null_

Tags: sas

I'm looking for report using SAS data step :

I have a data set:

```
Name Company Date
X    A       199802
X    A       199705
X    D       199901 
y    B       200405
y    F       200309
Z    C       200503
Z    C       200408
Z    C       200404
Z    C       200309
Z    C       200210
Z    M       200109
W    G       200010
```

Report I'm looking for:

```
Name Company From     To
X    A      1997/05   1998/02
     D      1998/02   1999/01
Y    B      2003/09   2004/05
     F      2003/09   2003/09
Z    C      2002/10   2005/03
     M      2001/09   2001/09
W    G      2000/10   2000/10
```

THANK you,

Tried using proc print but it is not accurate. So looking for a data *null* solution.

```
data  _null_;
set salesdata;
by name company date;

array x(*) from;
From=lag(date);
 if first.name  then count=1;
do i=count to dim(x);
x(i)=.;
end;
count+1;
If first.company then do;
from_date1=date;

end;
if last.company then To_date=date;
if from_date1 ="" and to_date="" then delete;
 run;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data _null_;
    set yourEvents;
    by Name Company notsorted;
    file print;
    If _N_ EQ 1 then put 
        @01 'Name'
        @06 'Company' 
        @14 'From'
        @22 'To'
        ;
    if first.Name then put 
        @01 Name
        @;  ** This instructs sas to not start a new line for the next put instruction **;
    retain From To;
    if first.company then do;
        From = 1E9;
        To = 0;
    end;
    if Date LT From then From = Date;
    if Date GT To   then To   = Date;
    if last.Company then put
        @06 Company 
        @14 From    yymm7.
        @22 To      yymm7.
        ;
run;
```

Comment: This solution does not require sorting and therefore respects the order of the input.

Answer (score 1):

I have done data step to calculate From_date and To_date

and then proc report to print the report by group.

```
proc sort data=have ;
    by Name Company Date;
run;

data want(drop=prev_date date);
    set have;
    by Name Company date;
    attrib From_Date To_date format=yymms10.;
    retain prev_date;
    if first.Company then prev_date=date;
    if last.Company then do;
        To_date=Date;
        From_Date=prev_date;
    end;
    if not(last.company) then delete;
run;

proc sort data=want;
    by descending name ;
run;

proc report data=want;
    define Name/order order=data;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, the simplest way is exploiting `proc report` and its `analysis` column type as the code below. Note that `name` and `company` columns are automatically sorted in alphabetical order (as most of the summary functions or procedures do).

```
/* your data */
data have;
    infile datalines;
    input Name $ Company $ Date $;
    cards;
X    A       199802
X    A       199705
X    D       199901 
y    B       200405
y    F       200309
Z    C       200503
Z    C       200408
Z    C       200404
Z    C       200309
Z    C       200210
Z    M       200109
W    G       200010
;
run;

/* convert YYYYMM to date */
data have2(keep=name company date);
    set have(rename=(date=date_txt));
    name = upcase(name);
    y = input(substr(date_txt, 1, 4), 4.);
    m = input(substr(date_txt, 5, 2), 2.);
    date = mdy(m,1,y);
    format date yymms7.;
run;

/****** 1. proc report ******/
proc report data=have2;
    columns name company date=date_from date=date_to;
        define name / 'Name' group;
        define company / 'Company' group;
        define date_from / 'From' analysis min;
        define date_to / 'To' analysis max;
run;
```

The html output:

[image: proc report]

(tested on SAS 9.4 win7 x64)

============================ OFFTOPIC ==============================

One may also consider using `proc means` or `proc tabulate`. The basic code forms are shown below. However, you can also see that further adjustments in output formats are required.

```
/***** 2. proc tabulate *****/

proc tabulate data=have2;
    class name company;
    var date;
    table name*company, date=' '*(min='From' max='To')*format=yymms7.;
run;
```

proc tabulate output:

[image]

```
/***** 3. proc means (not quite there) *****/

* proc means + ODS -> cannot recognize date formats;

proc means data=have2 nonobs min max;
    class name company;
    format date yymms7.;  * in vain;
    var date;
run;
```

proc means output (cannot output date format, dunno why):

[image]

You may leave comments on improving these alternative ways.